# Regexp and non-recording groups in C#

Tags: c#, regex, f#

I am having an issue with regexp in C#.
I've been using theses patterns in F# and it works fine, so i don't understand why it would'nt work in C#.

So let's say i've got a muline input file. I need to parse this file for specific data:

Exemple:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit (Token1 : 42)
    Aliquam id ante ut ante tempus fringilla Token2 (ante ut ) : 45
    Morbi varius adipiscing lacus, eget pellentesque tellus vulputate Token3 :  43
```

I basicaly need to retrieve the numbers written after Token1, Token2 , Token3 in a single match ( ie just want my number as a result).
The patterns i used in F# are the following ones:

```
PatternToken1 = "(?:Token1 : )(\d+)"
PatternToken2 = "(?:Token2.* : )(\d+)"
PatternToken3 = "(?:Token3 : )(\d+)"
```

So my issue is the following one :
pattern matching my input string in F# would give me the following results:

```
 MatchedToken1 = 42
 MatchedToken2 = 45
 MatchedToken3 = 43
```

In C# i would get the following results:

```
 MatchedToken1 = Token1 : 42
 MatchedToken2 = Token2 (ante ut ) : 45
 MatchedToken3 = Token3 :  43
```

How come this works in F# and not in C# ? What kind of pattern must i use for it to work in C#?

EDIT:
Here is the code i use to match my patterns in c#:

```
 abstract class  PatternMatcherBaseEntity<T>
{
    protected Regex Pattern;
    protected T Match;


    private static TK Convert<TK>(string input)
    {
        TK res=default(TK);
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TK));
        if(converter != null)
        {
            try
            {
                res = (TK) converter.ConvertFromString(input);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                res = default(TK);
            }

        }
        return res;
    }


    protected bool Matcher(string s)
    {
        var res = false;
        //var matchedData = Regex.Match(s, Patterm);
        var content = Pattern.Matches(s);
        if(content.Count>0)
        {
            //Match = Convert<T>(content.Value);
            Match = Convert<T>(content[0].Value);
            res = true;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public T MatchGetter(String stringToMatch)
    {
        T ret = default(T);
        if(stringToMatch != String.Empty)
        {
            ret = stringToMatch.Match()
            .With(Matcher, x => Match)
            .Else(x => default(T))
            .Do();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

by the way i've tested using verbatim strings and escape string. It would not compile otherwise

Comment: Please show the code you use to get the value of the match.

Comment: I just added the piece of code i'm using to match my patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
PatternToken1 = "(?<=Token1 : )(\d+)"
PatternToken2 = "(?<=Token2.* : )(\d+)"
PatternToken3 = "(?<=Token3 : )(\d+)"
```

Comment: Sure this would work, but to be consistent you should get rid of the capturing groups, you don't need them in your solution. But IMO lookbehinds are not needed here, just use the content of the capturing groups.

Comment: this did the trick i did not know about positive lookbehind  Thanks for the help !

Comment: You mean something like "Token1 : (\d+)" ?

Comment: @user901215 I assume this question belongs to me (you should put @USERNAME in your comments). No I mean `(?<=Token1 : )\d+`. The part of the lookbehind is not part of the matched string, so the part matched by this regex is only the \d+. You will get this then in content[0]. If you put brackets around the `\d+` you are creating a capturing group and because this is the first one you will find the content of this group in `content[1]`. I will improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:Token1 : )(\d+)
             ^   ^
```

With this brackets you are creating a capturing group that puts the match from within the brackets in a capturing group.

You uses it now like this

```
var content = Pattern.Matches(s);
```

now `Matches` returns an array where

`content[0]` contains the complete matched string

`content[1]` contains the matched part of group 1

and here

```
Match = Convert<T>(content[0].Value);
```

you are using the wrong part of the `MatchCollection` Array `content`

Your result is in group 1, so you need to get the group 1

```
Match = Convert<T>(content[1].Value);
```

Comment: what i see in debug is that content.Count == 1 so there is only one value in content which includes the tokem and the number. What you are describing to me looks more like the perl/javascript regex behaviour. But thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @user901215 No this is c#/.net. If count==1 then you had no capturing group in your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know F# but in C# you need to escape back slashes by doubling them up \\, or use the @ string prefix:

```
PatternToken1 = "(?:Token1 : )(\\d+)";
PatternToken2 = @"(?:Token2.* : )(\d+)";
PatternToken3 = @"(?:Token3 : )(\d+)";
```

Comment: If that was the problem it wouldn't even compile: ["Unrecognized escape sequence"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44ezxxy3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In C# you'll want (?:) to match but not include in the match result:

```
Regex.Match(str, @"(?:Token1) : (\d+)"); // result =  42
Regex.Match(str, @"(?:Token2).* : )(\d+)"); // result = 45
Regex.Match(str, @"(?:Token3).+:.+\d+"); // result = 43
```

EDIT - accidentally had a stray paran in there - thanks to commenter for pointing out - also, fully misunderstood the point of the question ... thought the OP wanted to get the match with the word - funny part is I even open the question with "to match but not include".  Not sure what I was thinking - anyways, new code and this time copy/paste to avoid extra paran ...

```
    string str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit (Token1 : 42)      Aliquam id ante ut ante tempus fringilla Token2 (ante ut ) : 45      Morbi varius adipiscing lacus, eget pellentesque tellus vulputate Token3 :  43  ";
    Match m1 = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=Token1 : +)\d+");
    Match m2 = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=Token2.* : +)\d+");
    Match m3 = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=Token3 : +)\d+");
    MatchCollection mAll = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<=Token\d[^\:]+: +)\d+");
```

Comment: The OP is already using noncapturing groups. And you have unmatched brackets in your answer.

Comment: @stema - thanks - fully reversed the answer and fat-fingered transposition of code - thanks for pointing out my pre-coffee carelessnes!